# chartjs and vue-chartjs error on build project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

In my project, I'm using typescript and class-based components. When I write `yarn-start` commands an error showing on the terminal and couldn't build project on netlify. I used two packages **charts** and **vue-chartjs**, and the error occurred for these two packages.

*package.json*

```js
{
  "name": "chobi-market",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "element-ui": "^2.11.1",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-animejs": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-images-loaded": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-masonry": "^0.11.7",
    "vue-page-transition": "^0.2.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  }
}
```

Terminal error and the same error in netlify build log

```js
ERROR in C:/Momin/Self/photo-droplet/node_modules/vue-chartjs/types/components.d.ts
7:27 Cannot use namespace 'ChartData' as a type.
    5 | export declare class BaseChart extends Vue {
    6 |   addPlugin (plugin?: object): void
  > 7 |   renderChart (chartData: ChartData, options?: ChartOptions): void
      |                           ^
    8 | }
    9 | 
ERROR in C:/Momin/Self/photo-droplet/node_modules/vue-chartjs/types/components.d.ts
7:48 Cannot use namespace 'ChartOptions' as a type.
    5 | export declare class BaseChart extends Vue {
    6 |   addPlugin (plugin?: object): void
  > 7 |   renderChart (chartData: ChartData, options?: ChartOptions): void
      |                                                ^
    8 | }
    9 | 
ERROR in C:/Momin/Self/photo-droplet/node_modules/vue-chartjs/types/mixins.d.ts
5:14 Cannot use namespace 'ChartData' as a type.
    3 | 
    4 | export declare class ReactiveDataMixin extends Vue {
  > 5 |   chartData: ChartData;
      |              ^
    6 | }
    7 | 
    8 | export declare class ReactivePropMixin extends Vue {
ERROR in C:/Momin/Self/photo-droplet/node_modules/vue-chartjs/types/mixins.d.ts
9:23 Cannot use namespace 'ChartData' as a type.
     7 | 
     8 | export declare class ReactivePropMixin extends Vue {
  >  9 |   readonly chartData: ChartData;
       |                       ^
    10 | }
    11 | 
No lint errors found
```

Comment: I'm sure you've thought about this but just in case: have you tried deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling?

Comment: Just now I did it, but the same result!

Comment: What version are you using? Apparently there should have been a fix for this in June: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/614

Comment: all package version is in `package.json` file.

Comment: Riiight, I was carelessly reading, haha. It's early in the morning, might explain it ;) But yes, you don't have the latest version, so that explains your error...